# laravel livewire wire:click is not working when i do insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

Laravel version: 8.7.1

livewire version: 2.x.x

You have to look at the code to understand my issue

this function will return a template for being rendered

```
function createElementForAttatchment(tit,capt,id){
    let template =
        ` <div class="approval-list-tab display-flex
            flex-direction-column flex-align-item-start
             flex-justify-content-space-between" wire:click="$emit('laucnhLeave',${id})">
                <h1 style="text-align: left">${tit}</h1>
                <h2>${capt}</h2>
            </div>`
    return template
}
```

below code will fetch data from the server and execute the above function

```
function getDataFromServer(){
        axios.get(appUrl+"/api/attendences/for/approval").then(response=>{
            console.log(response.data)
            let data = response.data.data
            nextPageUrl = response.data.next_page_url
            data.forEach(d => {
                let title = d.first_name + " " + d.last_name
                let caption = "ROll NUMBER : "+d.roll_number + " Class : "+d.student_class_id
                scollingElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",createElementForAttatchment(title,caption,d.id))
            })
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Now wire:click is not working . However i tested it separately, it worked fine but not working when i work with insertAdjacentHTML

Code for click event listener is :

```
Livewire.on('laucnhLeave', (id) => {
    alert(id)
})
```

Thank You !

Comment: Any reason why ?

Comment: Adding a `wire:click` using javascript does not work. There will be no javascript event linked to this button. `wire:click` should be added in a blade. That is how Livewire works, everything on the Laravel back-end, not on the JavaScript front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work . so i wrote the script something like:

```
document.getElementbyId('element-id').addEventListener('eventname',()=>{

})
```